# Javascript function in a Google Tag Manager variable only outputs boolean

Tags: javascript, undefined, google-tag-manager

For any other types of variables, it returns "undefined". For example, even if I write something as simple as this:

```
function() {
var lll = 'abcd'
    return lll
    //return 345
    //return false 
}
```

The function will return "undefined", in both string and integer cases. But if I return just "false", it works as intended. I tried creating another "javascript code" variable in GTM, doesn't work. I have very little experience with both javascript and GTM so I have no idea what could go wrong.

Update: okay, so now I fixed the strings and integers, the problem was that it wanted a function name (and in the example I was trying to copy, there wasn't one).
Now I have another problem - the function outputs undef if I add a line:

```
var trackers = ga.getAll();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The code example doesn't return undefined. Even if the other return statements are uncommented

Comment: Well in my case it does. If I run it in the console, everything is OK, but I need it to work as a "custom javascript code"-type GTM variable.

Comment: _"Well in my case it does."_ - please may you update the code to be a [mcve]?

Comment: I wrote all the code there is in the project, but I can't share the GTM project itself. The problem isn't with the code as it works when executed in the console, it must be some GTM-specific error

Comment: How are you using this function? Where is the code that stores/uses its returned value?

Comment: @evolutionxbox custom JS variable in Google Tag Manager is an anonymous function with a return value, so this is actually an mve (even if you need GTM to run it).

Comment: If you enable GTM preview mode, there is a tab named "errors". Look there to make sure that your code does not throw an error, because then the variable will return "undefined" no matter what (your example however does run fine in my GTM instance with both string and int values).

Comment: @DBS right now I don't even try to use it, just check the variables window in the debug mode and the value in this function is always "undefined" if it's not boolean. I also tried to create a tag with a special parameter, it's undefined there aswell.

Comment: @EikePierstorff nope, no errors

Comment: @EikePierstorff I updated OP, check please

Comment: add screenshots of your set up and debugging efforts.